# How to add report to layout using Arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, reports

I have a script that creates MXDs and layouts dynamically, i need to to add to each data frame in the layout report using arcmap report wizard rather then export to pdf, is it possible ?